# Will my python meta search engine require the use of a framework?

Tags: python, search-engine

I am building a meta search engine and am wondering if a python framework would be necessary? I've been looking a web2py and django and they both seem like overkill for what I need. The basic idea for my metasearch is as follows:

1. User enters data in search bar
2. The search query is preprocessed (tokenized)
3. The tokenized query is sent to 3 search engines through API's. Boolean terms will be recognised where specified by the user (e.g. car AND engine)
4. The results are returned and stored in a dictionary and/or multiple lists. Probably lists if possible
5. The results are aggregated using a Markov Chain algorithm and output to the user

I intend on using HTML for the front end stuff and python for the back end. If I don't need a framework for this, is there anything else that I need to consider?

Comment: Why would you want to use both PHP and Python? Pick one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman my web development skills are very basic. I was going to use PHP for form actions. If this can be done through HTML/Python then I will solely use Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on what you mean by “framework”. There are small HTTP frameworks for Python such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) or [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/). They make it much easier to do any kind of HTTP processing, compared to raw CGI, WSGI or what have you. Of course you can also process forms with them, so you don’t need PHP.

Comment: I don't want to have to use a framework at all, even a light one. It's an additional learning curve that I don't really need right now. I was hoping that using a python friendly server such as Apache would be a much easier alternative

Comment: @adohertyd: you are doing HTTP, and you need a library for that. Flask and Bottle are examples of small libraries to help you with HTTP. They just happen to dictate your control flow, which is why they are known as “micro-frameworks”. As for Apache, if you mean `mod_python`, don’t do that because you will make it harder to move to other software later.

Comment: @adohertyd You're completely mistaken if you think not using a framework will be less of a learning curve than using one. It's the other way round: the framework abstracts away the complicated things required to deal with web requests, leaving you to concentrate on the actual logic.

Comment: I have been trying to get to grips with web2py for a while and it's just not happening for me. I had also tried Grok but found the documentation poor and no resources for beginners. If it's a case that using a framework is the best option for a beginner then I will just have to do that.

Comment: @adohertyd: web2py, like Django, is a big framework which comes with a lot of stuff you (probably) don’t need. No wonder you find it overwhelming. But have a look at the “hello world” example in Bottle — http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/ — it’s 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends... you don't *need* a framework, but it'll make your job a lot easier, you could theoretically use the embedded server that comes with python, although you'd have to implement a lot of functionality on top of it.

From your description, I would advise going for a micro-framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).
You could go with something even more minimal like Bottle, but since you do need HTML forms and probably a database, Flask makes this a bit easier on you if you're a beginner, since it already has a templating engine included ([Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/)) and hooks for [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

I think this would a be a good compromise between having some work taken care of by the framework, and still not using something completely overkill like Django.

The learning curve isn't that steep at all and I think it's much less time consuming then not using any framework, since you can see how to do most of what you'll need in the examples, and it's not bloated to the point where things start getting in your way.